# safely de-energizing a junction box so that I can permanently cover it up

Tags: lighting, circuit-breaker, light-fixture, junction-box

I have a junction box in my ceiling that is controlled by a single light switch. I no longer want to use the junction box or have it exposed and I'd like to cover with drywall-- much preferable to a plastic cap or painted blank. I know typically this isn't legal or safe but I was wondering if it would be OK to do if I disconnected and capped the wires leading into the relevant light switch from my circuit--effectively de-energizing the junction box (there is nothing downstream of the junction box using those wires, they terminate in the box). The light switch would remain so anyone could access the wires there and also anyone could easily re-attach them to make use of the junction box in future. Thank you!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. If it isn't legal or safe, we aren't going to be able to tell you it'll be "OK". And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Hi--thanks! I was referring to drywalling over a live junction box as illegal and unsafe, but that's not what I'm proposing to do! I was trying to find out if people here thought my plan was either of those things and if so why-- because from what I can tell if I disconnect the wires leading into the box...it's not longer really even a junction box, it's just a metal box in a wall with some totally dead wires.

Answer (score 3):

Either remove the wires entirely, or if it is impossible to do so, remove as much of the cables at most ends obliterate the cables at both ends so they are entirely orphaned in the wall.  Don't get your cables mixed up!

Then, remove the old junction box entirely.  Gone.